# Is there any way to scrape Google Search results without getting blocked by Captcha?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, recaptcha, google-search

Say I wanted to scrape results from searching "hi google" (just an example). I'm using Puppeteer with Node.js to scrape. I use the following code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
scrape = async function () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/search?q=hi+google&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS879US879&oq=hi+google&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j46j69i60l3.1667j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8", { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 663 });
    await page.waitForSelector('.xpd');
    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        
        return document.querySelectorAll('.xpd')[16];

    });
    await browser.close();
    return data;

}
scrape()
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
```

When the browser launches, it immediately goes to a reCAPTCHA page: [image: reCAPTCHA]
Is there any way to surpass this issue? I've done some researching online, but those results are either 1. quite theoretical and I have no idea how to implement those in my code, or 2. Python solutions, and I'm not sure how some of those solutions would look with Puppeteer. The most helpful result I came across was randomly timing the scraping to make the requests seem human-like, but as you can see it's not working even retrieving just one data element, and it just immediately takes you to a reCAPTCHA page.

Thanks.

Comment: Set your browser user agent

Comment: @0m3r thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but now the output in the console is `{}` instead of the desired search result. I even used puppeteer-extra but it still doesn't fix.

Answer (score 8):

This is down to a large amount of factors.

First of all, you'll want to utilise `puppteer-extra-stealth` (https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth).

This library patches the most common methods in which puppeteer is detected.

Secondly, you also want to emulate realistic mouse movements. I've found the library `ghost-cursor` to work very well for that (https://github.com/Xetera/ghost-cursor).

That alone will not work, however. You also need to utilise non-spammed residential proxies or ideally 4g proxies.

4g proxies work off a pooled system based on the location and rotate and are shared among all mobile data users on that network in the area.

I recommend using https://rsocks.net UK or USA proxies - or ideally building your own 4g proxy locally to avoid any saturation.

You will still encounter some Captchas so it is worth implementing a solution such as 2captcha as well.

To further increase your success rate, you will want to use Google account cookies that have history and legitimate or "farmed" activity on them.

The more used the cookies attached to the account are for normal browsing, the more trust your session will have.